# Getting email address from a cell in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

How to get email id from a cell which contain more records?

For e.g. Cell *A1* has the following value:

> google rockstar@xyz.com www.google.com

I want to copy **rockstar@xyz.com** from the cell *A1* to *B1*.

Comment: Is Text to Columns a viable option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `RIGHT`, `LEFT` and `FIND` functions.  This works for me:

`=LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1,1)),FIND(" ",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1,1)),1))`

I used the space character to cut the string but it will only work if the email address is in the middle position.

Comment: Yes, the key here is the pattern of the data. If this exact formula doesn't work, you can work with the tools in this formula to find the exact data pattern that will be able to extract your e-mail address.

Comment: another code for this including multiple space.
`=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND("@",A1)-1)," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))&MID(A1,FIND("@",A1),FIND(" ",A1&" ",FIND("@",A1))-FIND("@",A1))`

Answer (score 6):

[@ArtiBucco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11243796/1369235) is correct. But including `TRIM()` function will also work on multiple space.

`=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND("@",A1)-1)," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))&MID(A1,FIND("@",A1),FIND(" ",A1&" ",FIND("@",A1))-FIND("@",A1))`

Answer (score 4):

This formula finds an email address anywhere within the text ([source](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1272-excel-extract-email-address.html)):

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1&" ",FIND("@",A1))-1)," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

For French users with Excel in French, you can use this function :

> =SUPPRESPACE(DROITE(SUBSTITUE(GAUCHE(A1;TROUVE(" ";A1&" ";TROUVE("@";A1))-1);" ";REPT(" ";NBCAR(A1)));NBCAR(A1)))